# Field projection in aggregation that differs from underscore id

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

According to MongoDB 3.4 release notes, MongoDB now supports fields projection in aggregation, that differs from underscore id. 
But, when I use

```
Aggregation.project().andExclude("*not_underscore_id_field*");
```

I see an error

```
Exclusion of field *not_underscore_id_field* not allowed. Projections by the mongodb aggregation framework only support the exclusion of the _id field!
```

(I see the same error on the latest, 1.10.6.RELEASE, version of spring-data-mongodb)

I didn't find an appropriate  ticket on spring-mongodb jira dashboard

So, this haven't been fixed yet, or this won't be fixed and I'm wrong?

Comment: It sounds like this is the intended behavior, as only `_id` fields are allowed to be excluded: `Projections by the mongodb aggregation framework ONLY support the exclusion of the _id field!`. Not a bug, just an unsupported feature.

Comment: This is here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields. Make sure you are using 3.4 server. Check `db.version() ` from shell to verify the server version.

Comment: I'm using 3.4.5 version of mongodb. This behaviour is a part of spring-mongodb code. In mongo, I can use an aggregation pipeline, where I'm adding a field ($addFields) firstly, and deleting this field (using $project) at the end.

Comment: Its still not supported in latest 2.0.0 release which is a 3.4 compatible release. You can log a jira [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel)

Answer (score 1):

As I see, inside `ProjectionOperation.andExclude(String... fieldNames)` we have next code:

```
for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
    Assert.isTrue(Fields.UNDERSCORE_ID.equals(fieldName),
            String.format(EXCLUSION_ERROR, fieldName, Fields.UNDERSCORE_ID));
}
```

So, it allows us to exclude **only** `_id` field

As solution you can specify all fields which you want to **include**:

```
Aggregation.project("fieldNames"...)
```

Comment: I saw this code too, thats why I asked my question. This feature is supported by mongo in 3.4